# Как получить $_GET параметр?

Tags: php, sql

Есть 2 запроса, один вставляет добавляет комментарий к записям, другой выводит их, каждой записи свои комменты

Запрос добавления коммента:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO comments(name, comment, post_id) VALUES (:name, :comment, :post_id)';
$sqlParams = [':name' => $_POST['name'], ':comment' => $_POST['comment'], ':post_id' => $_GET['id']];
```

Ну и вывод:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = :id';
$sqlParams = [':id' => $_GET['id']];
```

Проблема в том, что у меня не получается в первом запросе, в :post_id присвоить значение $_GET['id']. Сделал var_dump($_GET['id']) получил стринг, а post_id в таблице int, сделал жесткое преобразование ':post_id' => (int)$_GET['id'], в итоге вместо ожидаемого параметра $_GET['id'] допустим 500, я все время получаю 0

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `intval()`

Comment: Как вы передаёте и post и get?

Comment: В смысле как передаю get и post?

Comment: ':post_id' =>intval($_GET['id']??0)];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь в POST запросе получить GET переменную. Так делать не стоит. Запрос надо делать либо POST, либо GET.

Замените $_GET на $_POST переменную.

Скорее всего у вас есть некая форма или AJAX скрипт на js (JQuery), который отправляет данные:

```
':name' => $_POST['name'], ':comment' => $_POST['comment']
```

Добавьте к ним ещё и id полученный из $_GET['id'], тогда вы спокойно будете использовать строку:

```
$sqlParams = [':name' => $_POST['name'], ':comment' => $_POST['comment'], ':post_id' => $_POST['id']];
```

Сделать это можно либо добавив в форму

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" >
```

Либо в data $.ajax получив предварительно значение из URL.

Comment: Да, в самом верху затаился Ajax, который сволочь мне и пудрил мозги